# Access to my action edit from an other controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new on RoR, and I try to build a classic web app with post & user. 
There is a model & controller(Onlines) that allow the user to put his posts  on a common wall with new informations own to this action.
I'm currently trying to modify a nested form associated with this action(Onlines), by modifying the model Onlines. 
But I can't access to this action of my controller, and I don't understand why ?

My code ::

Onlines controller :

```html
class OnlinesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_online

  def edit
  end

  private 

  def set_online
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @online = Online.find_by(params[:id]) 
  end 

end
```

Post controller :

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_online


  def show
    @online.post_id = @post.id
  end

  private

  def set_online
    @onlines = Online.find_by(id: params[:id]) 
  end 

end
```

Views/posts/show : `

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <%= link_to '-  taked  - ', edit_online_path(@online), data: { confirm: 'Confirmer la mise en ligne de #{@title}?' }, class: "btn btn-primary " %>
</div>
```

Views/onlines/edit :

```html
<%= simple_form_for([@post, @onlines]) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="Order">
                <%= f.simple_fields_for :orders do |order| %>
                <%= render 'orders_fields', f: order %>
                <%end%>
                <div class="Order_links">
                  <%= link_to_add_association 'Ajouter une part', f, :orders, class: "btn btn-default" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

<div class="form-group text-center">
<%= f.submit "Pusher", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Routes:

```html
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'profiles/show'

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }

  resources :posts do 
resources :comments
resources :onlines 
end

  get ':pseudo', to: 'profiles#show', as: :profile
  get ':pseudo/edit', to: 'profiles#edit', as: :edit_profile
  patch ':pseudo/edit', to: 'profiles#update', as: :update_profile
  get ':post_id/online/new', to: 'online#new', as: :new_online
  post ':post_id/online/:id/edit', to: 'onlines#edit', as: :edit_online


  root 'posts#index'
```

So if you can guide me to succeed this action it would be wonderful, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, always refer to your models in singular form (Online in your case) as that is what Rails expects and controller's in plural as you have stated.  Be careful of your "before_action :set_online" statement as it is using the 'find' method for defining @post and will cause an exception if a param isn't passed in!  Also, your route is only showing a get request to get you to your edit_online page.  You'll then need a 'post' route linked to your 'update' action that will submit the data to your application after the user submits his/her form!  Provide the rest of your routes and I'll take a deeper look but also clarify your question a bit.  If you're just trying to go from one action in one controller to another action in a different controller you're looking to use the "redirect_to" statement.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer
I edit my question to show you all my routes
I'm not understand what you told me about set_online, should I have to restrict the action with only ?